# Insert "dates" with cmis in custom property type date

Tags: php, alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

I have a custom type `Clinical Record` where some field is `cli:date_created`. The type of this property is `Date`.

When I try to set this field (with php) I get `Argument of type "string" given but argument of type "\DateTime" was expected."`. But I am giving a Date and not a string.

```
'cli:date_created' => date('d/m/Y',strtotime($resultado[0]['fecha_alta'])),
```

What do I have to do in order to insert a date? Because I don't want to change the type from date to string in this field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do give a string argument as the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function returns string.

> Return Values ¶
>
> Returns a formatted date string. If a non-numeric value is used for
>   timestamp, FALSE is returned and an E_WARNING level error is emitted.

You need to pass a DateTime *instance*, e.g. using `new \DateTime()` constructor or another function that return a DateTime instance such as [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
'cli:date_created' => DateTime::createFromFormat('[yourformat]', $resultado[0]['fecha_alta']),
```